# Import CSV to highcharts scatterplot with tooltip populated by point name and x,y values

Tags: jquery, csv, highcharts

**The problem**
I need to import csv file into highcarts, where each point has its own name and values that also appear in the tooltip.

**What Iv'e tried**
Here is a working http://jsfiddle.net/r3w22eyq/8/ with a scatterplot that I created by entering the data. Id like to create the exact same chart but do so by importing from CSV. I would need the name, xcategory and ycategory to appear in the tooltip.

Thank you for any guidance.

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
            backgroundColor: '#EDEDED',
        type: 'scatter',
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Science and God'
    },

    xAxis: {
        title: {
            enabled: true,
            text: 'God is very important in my life (%)'
        },
        startOnTick: true,
        endOnTick: true,
        showLastLabel: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'The world is a lot worse off because of Science (%)'

        }
    },
    legend: {
       layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: 1000,
        y: 70,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF',
        borderWidth: 1
    },
    plotOptions: {
        scatter: {
            marker: {
                radius: 5,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: true,
                        lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                    }
                }
            },
            states: {
                hover: {
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                pointFormat: '{point.x} % Believe world is worse off because of science <br> {point.y} % Believe God is very important to my life'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Algeria',
        color: '#68228B',
        data: [[78.2,5.2]]
    },
    {
        name: 'Azerbaijan',
        color: '#68228B',
        data: [[90.2,2]]
    },
    {
        name: 'Argentina',
        color: '#68228B',
        data: [[28.4,2]]
    },
    {
        name: 'Australia',
        color: '#68228B',
        data: [[22,1.2]]
    },
    ]
});
```

});

Comment: Does your csv file have any particular structure?

Comment: Data point name, x value, y value

Answer (score 1):

Use the [data module](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-module) to load a csv file. To define a csv structure, set [data.seriesMapping](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.seriesMapping). For you case, it will be:

```
seriesMapping: [{
    name: 0,
    x: 1,
    y: 2
  }]
```

Also, you should use one series for all the points and change their color/symbol if you want - don't use a series per point, for many points the performance will be decreased significantly.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/2dkocaor/